# If double is not supported, how can I use float to achieve the same precision?

Tags: c, matlab, precision

I have a `C` code that do the right thing as I wish.

```
void create_weights(float alpha, float beta, float kappa, uint8_t L){

    /* Compute lambda and gamma parameters */
    double lambda = alpha * alpha * (L + kappa) - (double)L;

    /* Insert at first index */
    float Wm0 = lambda/(L + lambda);
    float Wc0 = Wm0 + 1 - alpha * alpha + beta;
    
    printf("Wm0 = %f, Wc0 = %f, lambda = %f\n", Wm0, Wc0, lambda);
    printf("Wci = 0.5f / (L + lambda) = %f\n",0.5f / (L + lambda));
}

int main() {
    
    create_weights(0.001, 2, 0, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Wm0 = -999998.875000, Wc0 = -999995.875000, lambda = -2.999997
Wci = 0.5f / (L + lambda) = 166666.648140
```

In MATLAB, the output is:

```
lambda = -2.999997000000000
Wm0 = -999999.0000082518 
Wc0 = -999996.0000092518
0.5 / (L + lambda) = 166666.6666680420
```

So I'm very close! But here is the problem. This line

```
double lambda = alpha * alpha * (L + kappa) - (double)L;
```

As you can see, I have mixed `double` and `float`. It's just for the test.

If I change that code to

```
double lambda = alpha * alpha * (L + kappa) - L;
```

Or this code (now it's only floats in the code):

```
float lambda = alpha * alpha * (L + kappa) - L;
```

Then I will get this output:

```
Wm0 = -967915.312500, Wc0 = -967912.312500, lambda = -2.999997
Wci = 0.5f / (L + lambda) = 161319.384615
```

So in this case, I'm in need of this line but I'm not allowed to use double because my processor does not support double.

```
double lambda = alpha * alpha * (L + kappa) - (double)L;
```

So what can I do, if I want to same floating precision with double, as in float?

Run the code here:
https://onlinegdb.com/dwwWtdf2S

Comment: *but I'm not allowed to use double because my processor does not support double* - your processor does not have to support `double`. In case there is no support for `double` in FPU, it is emulated in the software. Sounds like you want to emulate it anyway, so let the compiler do it for you.

Comment: You want to do `double lambda = (double)alpha * alpha * (L + kappa) - L;`, because evaluation is left-to-right, and `float` arguments will be promoted to `double` in a mixed arithmetic operation.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for the information.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes. But as I see, `lambda` variable gets the same result even if I use `(float)` or `(double)`

Comment: @MrYui I saw some compilers which are treating `double` same as `float` on processors without `double` FPU support, unless instructed otherwise. Maybe it is your case. Please tell us what processor we are talking about and what compiler. Alternatively run the same code on PC and compare the results.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well, I'm running at processors that have single precision floating. Such as STM32, AVR.

Comment: @EugeneSh. avr-gcc prior to v10 did not have double support at all.` double` and `long double` where treated as `float`. From v10 there is a special command line option -with-double and -with-long-double enabling those types. I believe that double multiplication will take many (if not tens) thousands of clock cycles and its usage is very limited.

Comment: @0___________ Yes, that's the issue here. I don't want to use `double`. I need to find a way around that.

Comment: @MrYui do not compare AVR to STM32. STM32F7 have double hardware FPU support. AVR are tiny 8 bits uCs. Even without that support double numbers operations are executed in reasonable time

Comment: @MrYui If you don't want use `double`, you won't get the precision of `double` calculations. But this is something you do want. There is no way around it, unless you want to implement it from scratch, which I doubt will be any more performant than the standard.

Comment: @0___________ Yes, But I'm poor and don't have any rich STM32 with luxury double precision. Only regular STM32 with single FPU.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, but what if I increase `alpha` ? In this case, `alpha = 0.001`. That's is a very small number.

Comment: Even STM32 without FPU  (M0, M3, M33) are powerful enough to do double operations in reasonable manner. 8 bit AVR dos not

Comment: @0___________ Yes, AVR has not. I want 100% portable C code.

Comment: Then scratch floating point completely and switch to fixed point

Comment: @EugeneSh. fixed point is the same painful for AVR as float :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. If I use `alpha = 0.1`, then it will work like charm for me (comparing with MATLAB = the truth). But if I want to use `0.01`, can't I like...divide `Wm0` with e.g `0.1` and scale up the number? E.g if I got the number `99` and I use `alpha = 0.1`. If I use `alpha = 0.01`, then I should get `999`.

Comment: @0___________ But 100% portable and without unexpected performance penalties or linked FP libraries :P

Comment: @EugeneSh. thruth

Comment: Thank you all for the conversation. Very helpful.